# SQL query not returns expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a table `DelieveryCalendarMaster` with data like this:

[image]

Now I am selecting records with this query:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[DelieveryCalendarMaster]  
for json auto
```

It returns a JSON result as seen here:

[image]

I want to merge object of the same date, like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to merge? What will happen to rest of fields? You can achieve that by using `GROUP BY` statement in SQL. But still, you have to decide how you want to aggregate corresponding data.

Comment: I tried with group by but not able to achieve output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Therefore, using `GROUP BY` together with `JSON` subquery.

```
SELECT t1.date, 
      (
         SELECT t2.id, t2.TimeSlot 
         FROM DelieveryCalendarMaster t2 
         WHERE t2.date = t1.date 
         FOR json auto
      ) as 'row' 
FROM tab DelieveryCalendarMaster t1 
GROUP BY t1.date 
FOR json auto
```

actually, it will return the row array in array wrapper, however, [it is not recommended](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/21/without_array_wrapper-new-important-change-in-for-json/) to remove it in the case of array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it will be help you.

```
SELECT [Date],
    (SELECT [Date],[TimeSlot],[Availability],[DisplayText]
    FROM [dbo].[DelieveryCalendarMaster] a  
    WHERE a.[Date] = e.[Date]
    FOR JSON AUTO  
    ) as Slots  
FROM [dbo].[DelieveryCalendarMaster] e  
Group BY e.[Date]
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('Dates')
```